# How to export raster with vector in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, mapping

I have a question.

I have a raster and vector.

And I want to export '.jpg' file as raster with vector.

Is there any way?

- raster is map
- vector is road of map

Comment: Are you asking how to [export an image of the current map canvas](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/map_views/map_view.html#exporting-the-map-view)?

Comment: @Erik Thanks!!! It works!!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Go to Project ► Import/Export ► saveMapAsImage Export Map to Image

If you want to get image without any space, select this option!

►► **Calculate from Layer**